# SQL selecting change date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, ssms

I have a table in SSMS:

```
Id  Date Value
111 1/1  x
111 1/2  x
111 1/3  y
111 1/4  y
111 1/5  x
111 1/6  x
222 1/3  z
222 1/5  x
222 1/7  x
```

I want to keep the record of the date where the Value changes.  So the output will be:

```
Id  Date Value
111 1/1  x
111 1/3  y
111 1/5  x
222 1/3  z
222 1/5  x
```

What would be a good way to query this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, lag(value) over (partition by id order by date) as prev_value
      from t
     ) t
where prev_value is null or prev_value <> value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this.

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE(Id  INT, Date VARCHAR(3) , Value VARCHAR(3) )
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES
(111, '1/1', 'x'), 
(111, '1/2', 'x'), 
(111, '1/3', 'y'), 
(111, '1/4', 'y'), 
(111, '1/5', 'x'), 
(111, '1/6', 'x'), 
(222, '1/3', 'z'), 
(222, '1/5', 'x'), 
(222, '1/7', 'x')

;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT  * ,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Id Order by [Date]) AS RN 
    FROM @MyTable
)
SELECT T1.* 
FROM CTE T1
    LEFT JOIN CTE T2 ON T1.Id = T2.Id AND T1.RN = ( T2.RN + 1 )
WHERE T1.Value <> T2.Value
    OR T2.Id IS NULL
```

Result:

```
Id          Date Value
----------- ---- -----
111         1/1  x    
111         1/3  y    
111         1/5  x    
222         1/3  z    
222         1/5  x
```